# Does any one know what this part is called?

Tags: chevrolet, leak, vacuum, aveo

I have 2007 Chevy Aveo and I need to replace this part but don't know what it is called. It's a "t" square that water runs through one part and air through the other and connects to the throttle body

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you certain water runs through this?

Comment: Looks like it is part of the pcv system with a check valve in one direction...

Comment: @SolarMike PCV is in the valve cover, more than likely it is just a tee.

Comment: @Moab a tee has 3 ports, that has 4...

Comment: Or a "cross", 4 vapor hoses ; looks like it may be a check in addition to the PVC.

Comment: I assume this is going to be some kind of vacuum/pressure relief/breather. It's attached to the cam cover, throttle (most likely for vacuum) and to the expansion tank. It's quite likely it's going to be simply allowing any pressure/vacuum to be released through the throttle, as well as any oil vapours to go into the intake.

Comment: PCV hose would be by his thumb. This looks to be a cross fitting which supplies vacuum out to the brakes on the right side. I don't think any coolant runs through this, as it wouldn't make sense to do so. I haven't found the part name or number.

Comment: Thank you everyone, still looking for a specific name to tell the guy at the parts store!

Comment: Take a picture and show it to the parts guy.

Comment: I tried he doesnt know what it is either

Comment: Can you give some more details about your car? Body type, engine type, what country you're in, etc?

Comment: Sedan, 1.6L,  america

Comment: @SolarMike being a little anal are you.....

Comment: @Moab just be rude : as you can't count...

Comment: @SolarMike yes you are rude...tee is a generic term in the auto business for any vacuum branch that has 3 or more branches.

Comment: Two others used the term « cross » perhaps you need an update...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I think I found your part. See diagram below:

[image: Aveo diagram cam cover]

You can see that the little T-junction is part of the PCV hose assembly (item 21 in the diagram). Unfortunately, this means you can't source the part separately, you'd need to buy the whole PCV hose. The part number of the PCV hose is **96474643**.